# How to determine from where <html> tag get it's margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a mobile version of the template and can't get rid of  right margin.
chrome inspector shows computed style : right-margin:0
but when i hoover my mouse over html in source i see orange rectangle to the right (which mean margin)

is there any way to determine from where the margin is coming?
i tried even changing every margin padding and border to 0 in css f***up all formatting but margin is still there so i suspect one of multiple javaScript on the side but there is to much of it to read it all in time.[image: no existing margin]

PS. Found what was causing the problem- absolute positioned arrow icon in div. But still it should be possible for browser to tell from where it get values it displays(the browser must know that to display it)

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: did you check that you had nothing larger than html/screen width ? Actually not enough to find out where it comes from , body margin not reset , positionning, or anything else

Comment: Margins aren't the only thing that could cause that.

Comment: On an unrelated note - you sure do love SO

Comment: Something I have noticed in chrome inspector vs. Firebug that sometimes magically margins popup for no apparent reason. I'd run this code through Firebug really quick and see if it shows anything. It could be the code or it could be Chrome. Firebug has 2 great tools that could also help you - the `layout` tab and the `computed` tab (like chromes) that might give you a better idea. Also check out InspectQ or something called like that (firefox extension). Allows you to view your page in 3d. Would be easy to see the margin from there.

Comment: In this case, I would recommend to use the built-in element inspector of FireFox (latest). From the computed CSS you can easily get back to the source CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress all margins around your page, put a 0 margin/padding/border to the `<html>` **and** `<body>` tags.

You should consider using a "reset CSS" just like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ (but there are many other ones).